# Can I pass a parameter to an Adobe Air app installer and use it at first startup?

Tags: installation, parameters, air

I need to offer the opportunity to install a personalized Adobe Air application from a website. Every user should be able to download an individual version of the app out of their user profile. Therefore i need to pass an id (e.g. the user id) to the installer which should be available at the first startup of the app, so that i can store it into a file or a sqlite database. I know that this could also be done straight out of the app through a login or by entering a username, but this is not an alternative. The app needs to the be personalized at the time the install process is started.

So far i have only little knowledge about developing applications with Adobe Air. I am just wondering if what i want to do is even possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just found a tutorial on how to do what i described above. To pass parameters from the installer to the application itself through the browser invoke event, you just have to modify the installer, if you are using the default sample installer which comes with the Adobe Air SDK.

http://www.davidtucker.net/2008/01/10/air-tip-5-passing-arguments-to-an-application-on-install/#

Comment: Can you also accept user inputs during installation? Is this possible in AIR?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it: http://cookbooks.adobe.com/post_How_do_I_use_command_line_arguments_with_my_AIR_ap-8003.html

Comment: This explanation shows how to get parameters from the startup of an application that is already installed, am i right? Does this also work for the installer? For example through the flashvars attribute in the embed tag.

I am now referring to installer like the one you see at htt://www.tweetdeck.com